# html page break adds 3 extra blank pages

Tags: html, css, page-break

When I use the page break attribute and then look at my page from i.e7 and click print preview, it generates 3 blank pages between the first and second page.

I have copied some sample code here: http://jsfiddle.net/vW54X/embedded/result/

You can't really replicate the error though because its embedded as an iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 does funny things with `page-break-after:always`.

Instead of applying it to your `div#cl`, create a new, empty `p` or `div` and apply it to that.  Place that after the `#cl`, so

```
<div id-"cl">
    //all your content
</div>

<div class="pageBreak">&nbsp;</div>
```

Style it with `page-break-after: always` but hide it until print.

Comment: Glad to help. That `div` might cause problems in your on screen design. If so, give it a `display:none;` in your stylesheet and then `display:block;` in your print stylesheet.  But if it is not giving you on screen probs, then leave it as is... all good.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is giving your body a `height: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar problem, I resolved it by setting the maximum height of each of my `<div>`s to a very small amount and gradually increasing it until the problem appeared again.

Basically, just this:

```
.your-container-div {
    max-height: 27.4cm;
}
```